# How do I"catch" every 7th item in a list?

Tags: php

I'm using [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) to list files. In this scenario my dir contains 19 files.

I need to create a list which wraps 7 files into a `<div>`.

I must be tired, because I'm not able to do this simple task.

**My code is updated to reflect suggestions below**:

```
$i = 0;
echo '<div class="first_div">';

foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
  if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
    if(($i % 7 == 0) && ($i > 0) )
      echo '</div><div>';

    echo 'My file';
    $i++;
  }
}
echo '</div>';
```

Any help appreaciated.

Comment: While this is about lines in a file, the same idea would work here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934364/displaying-multiple-lines-of-a-file-never-repeating/3934486#3934486

Comment: i'm not 100% sure what you are asking, but if you are looking for the seventh, the % operator might help you. if x % 7 = 0 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the mod operator (%) to determine if the current file number is the 7th one:

```
echo "<div>";
$i = 0;
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
   // Remainder is 0, so its the first of 7 files. 
   // Skip this for the first one, or we'll get a blank div to start with
   if($i % 7 == 0 && $i>0) echo "</div><div>";
   echo $filenamehere;
   $i++;
}
echo "</div>";
```

(Code is untested but should work)

**EDIT** : Used an independent counter for $i, since the index seemed to start at 2 and not 0 as expected.

Comment: It's not quite working. I'm using `$fileinfo->isFile()` so the $i always starts on 2 when I start adding files. Also, the div is addad for each file.

Comment: I updated the code to fix those issues you mentioned, try giving it another go and let me know if it works.

Comment: My updated code no longer relies on the index, but uses a plain ol' counter which increments by 1 for each file.  This should make the "index starts at 2" issue irrelevant.

Answer (score 7):

Something along these lines:

```
echo '<div>';

$i = 0;
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
   if($i % 7 == 0 && $i != 0) {
       echo '</div><div>';
   }
   // do stuff
   $i++;
}

echo '</div>';
```

Comment: @Tatu: This will output "<div></div><div>" prior to the first file.  You'll need to add " && i > 0" in the "if" statement to remove that first empty div (see my code).

Comment: Or maybe it won't, since @Steven is saying $i starts at 2 and not at 0, as I expected.

Comment: @webbiedave: In a comment on my answer below

Comment: Actually, using this gives one problem. The first `DIV` will only contain 5 items, since `$i` starts at 2. Therefore I had to go with Collins solution.

Answer (score 3):

or ssomething like

```
$chunk_size = 7;
foreach (array_chunk($dir, $chunk_size) as $chunk) {
   echo '<div>';
   foreach ($chunk as $fileinfo) {
      // echo list item $fileinfo here
   }
   echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Somesthing similar to this:

```
$c = 0;
foreach ($files as $file) {
  echo $file;
  if ($c % 7 == 0) {
    //7th file
  }
  $c++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using mod 7

```
$counter += 1;
if($counter % 7 = 0)
    //New div
```

Not 100% sure on syntax for this i Php but ther must be some

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) function to split an array to chunks.

```
<?
$dir_chunks = array_chunk($dir, 7);

foreach($dir_chunks as $dir)
{
    echo '<div>';
    foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
      if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
         // build list here
      }
    }
    echo '</div>';
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or (throwing out the % operator and putting in more [SPL](http://docs.php.net/spl))

```
<?php
$path = '......';
$nrit = new NoRewindIterator(new DirectoryIterator($path));
while ( $nrit->valid() ) {
  echo "<div>\n";
  foreach( new LimitIterator($nrit, 0, 7) as $it ) {
    echo '  ', $it, "\n";
  }
  echo "</div>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
if(($i-2) % 7 == 0)
```