# PHP for loop for rendering limited data

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I am using a flow player jquery to show latest 20 hot items, these items will be called directly from database.

The twist is the flow player divs.

One div can carry 5 items, like that I have to add 4 divs.

Each div contains just 5 items from the database, but the problem is how do I split the database equally in those 4 divs.

I tried the following code, but it just displays me the starting 5, How do I display the next 5 in another div and so on.....

```
$i = 0;
foreach($data as $idx=>$project_name)
{
    echo '<div>';
    echo $project_name['ProjectImage'];
    echo '</div>';
    if (++$i == 5) break;

}
```

And logic that will help me?

Comment: You want to split your results in divs that each contain 5 results ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [displaying multiple lines of a file, never repeating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934364/displaying-multiple-lines-of-a-file-never-repeating)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
foreach($data as $var=>$val) {
   if ($i == 0) echo '<div>';
   echo $project_name['val'];
   $i++;
   if ($i == 5) { 
      echo '</div>';
      $i = 0;
   }
}
```

in your code BREAK is the only problem... break will stop execution of loop and get you out of the loop.
this code will work fine for you

Comment: In your example, if there are 7 elements, the last (second) div won't get closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
foreach($data as $idx=>$project_name) {
   if ($i == 0) echo '<div>';
   echo $project_name['ProjectImage'];
   $i++;
   if ($i == 5) { 
      echo '</div>';
      $i = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: In your example, if there are 7 elements, the last (second) div won't get closed.

Comment: perhaps.  i'm not here to write their code for all eventualities ... just answering a question that specified blocks of 5

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
$i = 1;
foreach($data as $idx=>$project_name)
{
 if (($i = 1) || (($i % 5) == 0)){
    echo '<div>';
}
    echo $project_name['ProjectImage'];
 if (($i = 1) || (($i % 5) == 0)){
    echo '</div>';
}
$i++

}
```

Comment: In your example, if there are 7 elements, the last (second) div won't get closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 1;
foreach($data as $idx=>$project_name) {
   if ($i == 1 || $i % 6 ==0) echo '<div>';
   echo $project_name['ProjectImage'];
   $i++;
   if ( $i % 6 == 0 || sizeof($data) == ( $i -1) ) {
      echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: div must be closed when it's end of loop so sizeof($data) == ( $i -1) check is it at the end of loop or not !?

Comment: sizeof (alias of count) will return the number of elements in an array. For an array with one element it will return 1. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php - but I just see that you already increased `$i` at that point. **My fault**.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you could aquire the number of segments from the total elements of your data with a defined size of items per segment. Then you can iterate over the segements and within each segment you do the output ([**Demo**](http://codepad.org/os314OKD)):

```
$data = range(1, 32); # fake data

foreach(array_chunk($data, 5) as $items)
{
    # output per each segment:    

    echo '<div>';

    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        echo $item , " ";
    }

    echo '</div>', "\n";
}
```

Or for a more self-made chunking (**[Demo](http://codepad.org/pHvd06X9)**):

```
<?php
$data = range(1, 15); # fake data

$size = 5; # elements per div
$segments = range(1, count($data), $size); # segments

# iterate over segments if there are segments
if ($segments) while(each($segments))
{        
    # output per each segment:    

    echo '<div>';

    # iterate over the next $data elements, with a maximum of $size
    for($c = $size; $c-- && list($key, $item) = each($data);)
    {
        echo $item , " ";
    }

    echo '</div>', "\n";

}
```

In case you have the problem more than once inside your application and you want to re-use some code, you can encapsulate the needed logic inside an iterator if it's own:

```
class ArraySegments extends ArrayIterator {
    private $s;
    /**
     * @param array $array 
     * @param int $size of segment
     */
    public function __construct(array $array, $size) {
        $this->s = max(1, $size);
        parent::__construct($array);
    }
    public function current() {
        $segment = array();
        $c = $this->s;
        while($c && $this->valid()) {
            $segment[] = parent::current();
            --$c && $this->next();
        }
        return $segment; 
    }
}
```

Used as such:

```
$data = range(1, 15); # fake data

foreach(new ArraySegments($data, 5) as $elements) {
    printf(":::\n");
    foreach($elements as $element)
        printf(" - %s\n", $element)
        ;
    printf(";;;\n");
}
```

Just pass the array you want to iterate over (`$data`) and the number of items per segment (`5` in the example). Inside the outer foreach you then have at max 5 elements inside the `$elements` array. Example output:

```
:::
 - 1
 - 2
 - 3
 - 4
 - 5
;;;
:::
 - 6
 - 7
 - 8
 - 9
 - 10
;;;
:::
 - 11
 - 12
 - 13
 - 14
 - 15
;;;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`array_chunk()`function](http://php.net/array_chunk) for splitting the array into chunks first.