# Wrapping a div around every third item in a foreach loop PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

```
//set the array
$info = array(
'andy' => 'blue',
'andrew' => 'black',
'mark' => 'green',
'jane' => 'orange',
'simon' => 'red',
'joan' => 'pink',
'sue' => 'yellow',
'alan' => 'black') 


$i = 1;

foreach($info as $key => $val){

    <div class="holder">
        <div class="name">
            <?php echo $Name ?> 
        </div>
        <div class="colour">
            <?php echo $colour ?> 
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

This dispalys each "holder" class... but what I am wanting to do is wrap a container around the "holder" class and have 3 "holder" in each "container". 
eg:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="holder">
            <div class="name">
                <?php echo $Name ?> 
            </div>
            <div class="colour">
                <?php echo $colour ?> 
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="holder">
            <div class="name">
                <?php echo $Name ?> 
            </div>
            <div class="colour">
                <?php echo $colour ?> 
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="holder">
            <div class="name">
                <?php echo $Name ?> 
            </div>
            <div class="colour">
                <?php echo $colour ?> 
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I cant find out how to either get the index of the associative array, or how to break a foreach loop once %3 == 0.

Any suggestions would be awesome!

-Ved

Comment: So you are actually *asking* how you can increment the `$i` variable per each iteration? Not really, aren't you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [displaying multiple lines of a file, never repeating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934364/displaying-multiple-lines-of-a-file-never-repeating)

Comment: I can increment easy enough by putting i++ in the foreach. I just cant seperate $i when its % 3

Comment: See the link Gordon has in his comment. Actually both links. That function works easily and looks like it is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to have a separate counter variable:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($info as $key => $val){
  if($i%3 == 0) {
    echo $i > 0 ? "</div>" : ""; // close div if it's not the first
    echo "<div class='container'>";
  }
  ?>
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="name">
            <?php echo $Name ?> 
        </div>
        <div class="colour">
            <?php echo $colour ?> 
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
</div> <!-- close last container div -->
```

Comment: Turns out, yours was the solution for me. Thanks for the help

Comment: @chiborg, this code doesn't generates fully correct HTML. For last iteration a container tag remains to be closed. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: @ParthVora Did you see the last line? that should close the container in any case (except when `$info` is empty).

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for this? [php.net/array_chunk](http://php.net/array_chunk)

And, you have some syntax error there

```
foreach($info as $key => $val){
```

this should be

```
foreach($info as $key => $val){ ?>
```

closing php to start the HTML tag

Comment: I think this is what I needed! I never seen array_chunk before. Thanks muchly :)

Comment: This solution is better. Simply and pro!

Answer (score 1):

You would want to do something like this in that case. Make sure to get the variables right.

```
$i = 1;

foreach($info as $key => $val){
    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
         ?>
         <div name='container'>
         <?php
    }
    ?>
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="name">
            <?php echo $key; ?> 
        </div>
        <div class="colour">
            <?php echo $val; ?> 
        </div>
    </div>

    if ($i % 3 == 2) {
         ?>
         </div>
         <?php
    }

    <?php
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: I think array_chunk was the function I needed. Thanks all for the comments :D

Comment: Check Prakash's answer as the answer then. He would appreciate it.

Comment: @Martin, I think here $i should be initialized with 0 not 1. Furthermore, it keeps a container tag uncompleted for the last element. Do you know how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can increment `$i` it inside the foreach loop, e.g:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($info as $key => $val) {
    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: When I done this and places the 'container' div inside it would wrap only one holder, not the 3 'holders'.

Comment: @Ved: you should be opening the container div when ($i % 3 == 0) and closing it when ($i % 3 == 2). It seems from your above comment that you are doing both at the same iteration.

Comment: It may solveusing this solution.  http://www.chandansharma.co.in/each-div-contains-only-3-items-using-foreach-loops-in-php/