# Wordpress - WP_Query, pulling in multiple post

Tags: php, custom-post-type, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

Somewhat new to Wordpress and PHP and trying to work though this issue. I have a page (http://www.moderateindividual.com.php53-13.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/) and twards the bottom you can see a section with 6 images, I need those to be pulled in from a custom post type with a custom taxonomy. What I have now its just pulling in one post over and over, how would I make this pull in the 6 latest post in that category?

Here is my code I have so far

```
<?php 
//Define your custom post type name in the arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'news',   
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'news_category',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => '47',
        ),
        ),
    );
//Define the loop based on arguments
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
      <div class="st_views">
        <div class="tab-1 st_view">
          <div class="st_view_inner">
            <div class="row cat-title">
                <p><span>As To Them Shall Seem Most Likely…</span> / Nullam quis dolor interdum erat dapibus aliquam. <a href="#">View all</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="row top-stories">
              <div class="small-12 medium-8 large-8 columns main-news img-wrap"> <?php the_post_thumbnail('home-featured-thumb'); ?>
                <div class="story-title">
                  <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                  <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" />Read More</a></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--End Large-8 Columns-->
              <div class="large-4 small-12 medium-4 columns">
                <div class="row news-top img-wrap"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" /><?php the_post_thumbnail('home-thumb'); ?></a>
                  <div class="story-title-sub">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" /><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row news-bottom img-wrap"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" /><?php the_post_thumbnail('home-thumb'); ?></a>
                  <div class="story-title-sub">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" /><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--End Large-4 Columns--> 
            </div>
            <div class="row bottom-stories">
              <div class="large-4 medium-4 small-12 columns img-wrap"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" /><?php the_post_thumbnail('home-thumb'); ?></a>
                <div class="story-title-sub">
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" /><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--End Large-4 Columns-->
              <div class="large-4 medium-4 small-12 columns img-wrap"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" /><?php the_post_thumbnail('home-thumb'); ?></a>
                <div class="story-title-sub">
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" /><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--End Large-4 Columns-->
              <div class="large-4 medium-4 small-12 columns img-wrap"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" /><?php the_post_thumbnail('home-thumb'); ?></a>
                <div class="story-title-sub">
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" /><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--End Large-4 Columns--> 
            </div>
            <!--End Row--> 
          </div>
          <!--End st view inner--> 
        </div>
        <?php endwhile;?>
        <!--End tab 1 st view-->
```

The code above was me just searching the google for something that might work.

Any help or advice would be great.

Comment: The code in between your while loop is what will be output for each result the query finds, so the loop is working as expected -you're just outputting the same link and title over and over. Reduce your loop to only the code you want to repeat for each post.

Comment: So create a new array, $arg and loop for each post I want to display?

Comment: No, i would read up a bit on how a loop works in PHP. Start here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping.asp

Comment: I see, normally when I do it I just have like one <ul> and display all my post in the <li> and repeat as needed, the thing that is holding me up this time is that I need to drop all of them inside custom divs and columns and just cant repeat one.

Comment: Yeah, that gets more complicated but can be done if you set a counter on the loop. Then you can inject opening and closing div tags or different markup for each post based on the count. Something like this should help you out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270870/wrapping-a-div-around-every-third-item-in-a-foreach-loop-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to make 2 loops and use the [offset](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) parameter

```
<div class="st_views">
<div class="tab-1 st_view">
<div class="st_view_inner">
<?php 
//Define your custom post type name in the arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'news',   
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'news_category',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => '47',
        ),
        ),
    'posts_per_page' => 3
    );
//Define the loop based on arguments
$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); if ( $loop->have_posts() ):?>
<div class="row cat-title">
<p><span>As To Them Shall Seem Most Likely…</span> / Nullam quis dolor interdum erat dapibus aliquam. <a href="#">View all</a></p>
</div>
<div class="row top-stories">
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<?php if( $loop->current_post == 0 ){?>     
<div class="small-12 medium-8 large-8 columns main-news img-wrap"> <?php the_post_thumbnail('home-featured-thumb'); ?>
     <div class="story-title">
           <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
           <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></p>
     </div>
</div>
<!--End Large-8 Columns-->
<?php } elseif( $loop->current_post == 1 ){?>
<div class="large-4 small-12 medium-4 columns">
<div class="row news-top img-wrap"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('home-thumb'); ?></a>
       <div class="story-title-sub">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
       </div>
</div>
<?php } elseif( $loop->current_post == 2 ){?>  
 <div class="row news-bottom img-wrap"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('home-thumb'); ?></a>
      <div class="story-title-sub">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
<!--End Large-4 Columns--> 
<?php }?> 
<?php endwhile;?> 
</div> 
<?php  endif; //End Top Stories?>            
<?php 
//Define your custom post type name in the arguments
$args2 = array(
    'post_type' => 'news',   
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'news_category',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => '47',
        ),
        ),
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'offset' => -3
    );
//Define the loop based on arguments
$loop2 = new WP_Query( $args2 ); if ( $loop2->have_posts() ):?>          
<div class="row bottom-stories">           
<?php while ( $loop2->have_posts() ) : $loop2->the_post(); ?>            
<div class="large-4 medium-4 small-12 columns img-wrap"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('home-thumb'); ?></a>
     <div class="story-title-sub">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
     </div>
</div>
<!--End Large-4 Columns-->
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<!--End Bottom Row--> 
<?php endif;?>       
</div>
<!--End tab 1 st view inner-->         
</div>
<!--End tab 1 st view--> 
</div>
<!--End st view-->
```

Comment: I retract my previous statement and the help you gave me worked good, got it working just like i imagined. Thank you so much mark your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks again.