# Wrap data in container after each 3 iterations using PHP

Tags: php, iteration

First of all I know this question(or similer) has been already asked for several times, but I didn't get 100% perfact answer anywhere.

I want to wrap each 3 array elements in a container div. like:

Array $arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]; should be represented like below:

```
<div class="container">
<p>0</p><p>1</p><p>2</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
<p>3</p><p>4</p><p>5</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
<p>6</p>
</div>
```

Note: $arr can have any no of elements (not fixed).

I have found lot of post which gives above result, but they have issues with HTML. They are not generating 100% correct HTML(Keep left **uncompleted** HTML tags for last container tag). I want to achieve same result with **valid HTML** i.e all tags should be completed properly.

Note: I want to achieve it using simple loops and variables(wihtout using any built in array functions etc.).

This answers is pretty close, but has uncompete HTML tags.
[Wrapping a div around every third item in a foreach loop PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270870/wrapping-a-div-around-every-third-item-in-a-foreach-loop-php)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How hard would it be for you to attempt to complete the HTML tags? Did you want someone to just give you the code?

Answer (score 0):

you need for loop and steps 3 for example:

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<count($arr);$i+3): ?>
   <div class="container">
   <p>$arr[0+$i]</p><p>$arr[1+$i]</p><p>$arr[2+$i]</p>
   </div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

and don't forgot check array item by function `isset($arr['key'])`