# Wrap every 4 posts in a custom wordpress loop with a div

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, row

```
    <?php
      $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'college',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'order' => 'DESC',
      'orderby' => 'menu_order'
      );

      $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
      if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
      while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

      <div class="col-3">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
      </div>

   <?php
   endwhile;
   endif;
   wp_reset_postdata();
   ?>
```

Hi,
I've never done this before. I'm trying to wrap every 4 posts in the loop above inside a `<div class="row"></div>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should sort you out

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'college',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($the_query->have_posts()) :
    $counter = 0;
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
        if ($counter % 4 == 0) :
            echo $counter > 0 ? "</div>" : ""; // close div if it's not the first
            echo "<div class='row'>";
        endif;
        ?>
        <div class="col-3">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        $counter++;

    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Adapted from [Wrapping a div around every third item in a foreach loop PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270870/wrapping-a-div-around-every-third-item-in-a-foreach-loop-php)

Comment: Great :) it was  a nice challege, had me scribbling a few stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can follow my code, post of @chapskev is good but missing a closing div after end if

```
<?php $counter = 0; // 4  per list ?>
<?php foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  if ($counter % 4 == 0) :
    echo $counter > 0 ? "</div>" : ""; // close div if it's not the first
    echo "<div class='group'>";
  endif;
  echo 
  <<<TEXT
  <span>content</span>
  TEXT;
  $counter++;
  }
  echo "</div>";
?>
```